# Express Excel DATEVALUE in Python

Tags: python, excel

If I subtract the value of the cell normally marked as below in Excel, it comes out as a decimal point as shown below.

I need the value of column "=B-A".

Can you explain why the value of "B-C" comes out?
Can you do it in Python so that it can come out as below?

Please help me

| A | B | =B-A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:16:17 | 09:00:00 | 0.030359 |

Comment: _Can you explain why the value of "B-C" comes out?_ No, because you have not shared the code, or formula, or whatever you're using to produce this spreadsheet.

Comment: That is question also i’d like to know. i input the excel “b-a” that result came out

Comment: It is the old chestnut: the difference between how Excel stores the value, and how it displays it. Excel *stores* all datetime values as `double`. Cells A & B are *displayed* with the `Time` format, while C is just `General`. If you format cell C as `Time` it will appear as `00:43:43`, but the value Excel is storing (and which Python will read) is still `0.030359`.